# Function evaluates to true, but using function as parameter of if-statement shows false

Tags: java, recursion, boolean-logic

I have an assignment that calls for creating a person object.

```
    class Person {
        private String name;
        public Person parent1 = null;
        public Person parent2 = null;
        public Person spouse = null;
        public int numChildren = 0;
        public LinkedList<Person> children = new LinkedList<Person>();

        public Person(String n) {
            name = n;
            numChildren = 0;
        }
```

Three functions of my program, M, Y, and Z, do the following:

M — Marry the two people.

```
        public static void M(String name, String name2) {
            if (findPerson(name).getSpouse() != null && findPerson(name).getSpouse().getName().equals(name2))
                System.out.println(name + " and " + name2 + "are already married.");
            else if (Y(name, name2) || Z(name, name2) || Z(name2, name))
                System.out.println("Unable to complete action. " + name + " and " + name2 + " are related.");
            else if (findPerson(name).spouse != null)
                System.out.println(findPerson(name).getName() + " is already married.");
            else if (findPerson(name2).spouse != null)
                System.out.println(findPerson(name2).getName() + " is already married.");
            else
                findPerson(name).marry(findPerson(name2));
        }
```

Y — States whether name2 is an ancestor of name1.

```
        public static boolean Y(String name, String name2) {
            if (name.equals(name2))
                return true;    
            else if (findPerson(name).getParent1() != null)
                Y(findPerson(name).getParent1().getName(), name2);
            else if (findPerson(name).getParent2() != null)
                Y(findPerson(name).getParent2().getName(), name2);
            else if (findPerson(name2).getParent1() != null)
                Y(findPerson(name2).getParent1().getName(), name);
            else if (findPerson(name2).getParent2() != null)
                Y(findPerson(name2).getParent2().getName(), name);
            return false;
        }
```

Z — States whether name2 is a descendant of name1.

```
        public static boolean Z(String name, String name2) {

            LinkedList<Person> c1 = findPerson(name).getChildren();

            for (int i = 0; i < findPerson(name).getNumChildren(); i++) {
                if (c1.get(i).getName().equals(name2))
                    return true;
                else if (c1.get(i).getNumChildren() != 0)
                    if (Z((c1.get(i).getChildren().get(0).getName()), name2))
                        return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I use Y and Z to determine if name and name2 are related in any way. If they are, then in the function M, the second if statement prints out a message end exits the function.

Other related functions:
P — Record that name is a parent of name2.
T — Print out the tree of descendants of the specified person.

An example of a test input I've been working with:

```
    O Jon  
    O Jane  
    O Daniel  
    O Kevin  
    O Atticus  
    P Atticus Jon  
    P Atticus Jane  
    P Jon Daniel  
    P Jane Kevin  
    T Atticus

    Atticus
        |---->Jon
        |       |--->Daniel
        |---->Jane
                |--->Kevin
```

However, when I try to call M(Daniel, Kevin) it marries them, even though they're related (they would be cousins).

I input the line of code:

```
    System.out.println(name + ", " + name2);
```

at the top of the function Y; for the sample input above, the output is:

```
    Daniel, Kevin
    Jon, Kevin
    Atticus, Kevin
    Jane, Atticus
    Atticus, Atticus
```

So it's finding that Daniel and Kevin share a grandfather, Atticus.

I did a similar print statement and verified that my function was evaluating to true for this input, since the first thing Y checks is if name.equals(name2), in other words, ("Atticus").equals("Atticus").

But it's not triggering the second if-statement in M, and I don't know why. Am I missing something really simple?

If you'd like to see the rest of my code, let me know and I'll make an edit.

Comment: do the rest work?

Comment: @RyanTurnbull Yes, everything else in the program works as it's supposed to.

Comment: Is it the case that first `if-statement` in your method `M` is anyhow executed?

Comment: @procrastinator No, that checks to see if the two names given are already married, which they are not. If it did execute, then it would print out the message nested in it.

Comment: What happens when you have used the whole alphabet worth of functions? (hint: I think you should use more specific names and perhaps even make them methods)

Comment: @Sylwester They are methods. The only things that aren't methods are my getters/setters in my class Person. Everything else (all of these functions, my main, etc.) is in a separate class. But you do bring up a good point. I originally made the function name the same as the letter input, but have yet to change it.

Comment: @danban they are static methods. Ie. functions. `Fun(a, b)` =>  `a. method(b) `

Comment: @Sylwester Ah, unfortunately I am limited by my assignment's guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `Y` will return `true` if and only if the names equal. It will run all the other checks, but then return `false` in the end. You probably meant to return the results of the recursive calls instead.

Comment: You are correct. I just threw a return in front of my recursive calls, that solved the problem. So it was resolving as true, but there was no call to return, so it moved down the line and eventually returned false. Silly me.
Thanks!